# included drupal themes not working

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, theming

i installed drupal on my localhost. Whenever I try to change the theme to one that is included in the install (such as seven, or stark), no changes happen. When I enable the theme drupal says "x theme has been enabled", but I never see any changes. I tried emptying drupals cache, but that changed nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the theme and set it as default.
[image: Set as default or enable and set as default]